# Two fold increase in memory consumption of an Asp.Net App. when profiled

Tags: c#, asp.net, memory, profiler

I am writing a Profiler for Dot Net. In some situations, when I attach my Profiler to an Asp.Net application (running in production) I observe a 100%, or more, increase in the Working Set size.

I have taken several Dumps of the client application with and without the profiler and tried to find an explanation to the increase in memory (more then 500 Mb increase in one case) and couldn't!

I have Used Visual Studio 2015 "Debug Managed Memory", PerfView, DebugDiag2.2 and compared Dump files taken over time as memory Increases and could not find a memory leak or other explanation for the enormous increase in memory consumption!

What am I missing? How Can I find the cause of such a huge memory consumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have found out that the compilation debug flag was set to TRUE in the web.config.

Also we verified that all modules in use by the application were not compiled in debug mode.

Memory consumption is now as expected!